# How to add a specific keyboard layout in LXDE?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, lxde

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and LXDE. I use a phonetic keyboard layout to write Bengali in Unity. Now, I want to use LXDE, because of its better performance on my PC, but problem is that, I can't get that specific layout on LXDE.

How can I get that on LXDE?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=87702.0) might help. Basically it says to put a keyboard config on the main panel and then use it to change your layout.